# Router path parameter changes to [object Object]?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

```
policyClicked(policy: Policy){
    console.log(policy.name);
    this.router.navigate(['/policy',{projectId: this.project._id},{policyName: policy.name}]);
}
```

Im trying to execute this piece of code to route to the path provided. But i keep getting an error:

Error: Cannot match any routes: 'policy;projectId=uSpGcJFtxHK3vLGht/[object Object]'

Like the last parameter is getting lost or something. I put some logs in there to see if the value is undefined but its there. Heres where the route is defined also.

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', component: DashBoardHome},
    {path: 'project/:projectSearchResultId', component:     ProjectSearchResultsDetails},
    {path: 'search/:projectSearchValue', component: ProjectSearchResults},
    { path: 'login',        component: Login },
    { path: 'signup',       component: Signup },
    { path: 'recover',      component: Recover },
    {path: 'policy/:projectId/:policyName', component: PolicyDetails}
];
```

Comment: So if i change the code to: `this.router.navigate(['/policy',this.project._id,policy.name]);` it work. Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you're passing an object (the code in braces {}) so Javascript is interpreting it as an [object] which is why you got that strange error.  By passing it without braces, Javascript can use the actual text.

You may consider trying it this way, too:

```
var URL = '/policy/' + this.project._id + '/' + policy.name;
this.router.navigate(URL);
```